# Is this an appropriate site to ask questions about topics in medical school?

Tags: discussion, support

During my medical entrance examination preparation, I used

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/

https://biology.stackexchange.com/

https://physics.stackexchange.com/

These sites welcome posts where you could submit a "homework" (which was the tag used) style question, post your working, and have people comment on it/guide you. They were a big part of me getting into medical school, as instead of getting stuck for hours researching one minute detail I could write a question and come back later.

Is there something similar for medical school questions?

I often find myself getting stuck interpreting things - e.g. what exactly does and doesn't constitute the C and V parts of CHA2DS2VAS. (Note, I am not asking this question here, I am just using it as an example for context).

Are these types of questions suitable for Medical Science Stack Exchange (and is there a particular tag to use?, and if not, would anyone know of any websites that are suitable?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Homework questions are fine as long as they meet the prior research requirement. Using your example, we would expect you to know what CHADS-Vasc stands for, but asking what actually constitutes the "C" or "V" part would be a good question. (Do yourself a favor and drop the "2" part from the acronym. Everyone knows what you mean by CHADS-Vasc and adding the "2" part just makes it the most ridiculous acronym in the world.)

There doesn't appear to be a homework tag currently, but feel free to create it when you make your first post.

Comment: Great. Thank you for the information, both regarding my question and the CHADS-Vasc tip.